# Tableau filter using selected values

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm new to Tableau and learning as I'm doing. I have a datasource that has a column of say 30 distinct values. I want to create a filter on a dashboard based on 2 specific values and an ALL option. So if it were to be a drop down, the three options would be:

```
All [this should be the default]
Option 1
Option 2
```

Where selecting Option 1 or Option 2 filters would show only the selected datapoints and select ALL would show datapoints with any of the 30 distinct values.
I can create the filter with the 2 options, but cannot figure out how to include an ALL selection.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try using a set filter where you only keep the options you need , drag this see to the filter and select "In"